# "Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals'" - PDE is installed

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, pde

I am trying to create a basic grammar in xtext, such as the default below:

```
grammar x.Y with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate x "http://www.Y.x"

Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

However, I am getting an error:

> Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar
>   'org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals'.

Searching the web, the suggestion is to install Eclipse Plug-in Development Tools (PDE). I have done that, but the problem remains (after cleaning the project).

I have also tried the RCP Eclipse Nero package and the problem remains.

I have installed Java SE 1.8 and I am using Eclipse Nero (RCP and non-RCP).

I can't find any more suggestions on the web, the only one seems to be to make sure PDE is installed. Any ideas?

UPDATE

The defaults were set in the project set-up.

Project structure screenshot:

[image]

Manifest problems are below:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.equinox.common' cannot be resolved  MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl/META-INF   line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.ui.editors' cannot be resolved  MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui/META-INF    line 13 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.ui.ide' cannot be resolved  MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui/META-INF    line 14 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.ide' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/META-INF   line 9  Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.junit4' cannot be resolved    MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.tests/META-INF  line 12 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.testing' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.tests/META-INF line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.testing' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.tests/META-INF  line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui/META-INF    line 12 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui/META-INF    line 11 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.ui' cannot be resolved    MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui/META-INF    line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ide' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/META-INF   line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.junit' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.tests/META-INF  line 13 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.testing' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.tests/META-INF line 11 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.testing' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.tests/META-INF  line 11 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext.xbase' cannot be resolved MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl/META-INF   line 9  Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.eclipse.xtext' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl/META-INF   line 8  Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.junit' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.tests/META-INF line 9  Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle 'org.junit' cannot be resolved   MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.tests/META-INF  line 9  Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle com.ibm.icu cannot be resolved   build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 19 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.apache.commons.logging cannot be resolved    build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 17 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.apache.log4j cannot be resolved  build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 18 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore cannot be resolved build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 12 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils cannot be resolved build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 13 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch cannot be resolved   build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 14 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib cannot be resolved  build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 15 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.xtext.common.types cannot be resolved    build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xbase cannot be resolved   build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 9  Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator cannot be resolved build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 11 Plug-in Problem
>   Bundle org.objectweb.asm cannot be resolved build.properties    /org.xtext.example.mydsl    line 16 Plug-in Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals'. MyDsl.xtext /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 1 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/MyDsl.xtext    Grammar Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'baseName'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 13 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'code'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 26 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'component'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 10 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'configuration'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 11 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'createEclipseMetaData'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 24 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'eclipsePlugin'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 18 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'eclipsePluginTest'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 21 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'enabled'. GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 16 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'enabled'. GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 19 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'enabled'. GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 22 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'encoding'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 27 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'fileExtensions'.  GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 34 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'fileHeader'.  GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 29 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'generateStub'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 37 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'language'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 32 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'lineDelimiter'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 28 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'name'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 33 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'project'. GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 12 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'rootPath'.    GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 14 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'runtimeTest'. GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 15 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'serializer'.  GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 36 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'validator'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 39 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'StandardLanguage'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 32 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'StandardProjectConfig'.  GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 12 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'Workflow'.   GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 8 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2 MWE2 Problem
>   Couldn't resolve reference to JvmType 'XtextGenerator'. GenerateMyDsl.mwe2  /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 10 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/GenerateMyDsl.mwe2    MWE2 Problem
>   ID cannot be resolved to a rule MyDsl.xtext /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl    line: 9 /org.xtext.example.mydsl/src/org/xtext/example/mydsl/MyDsl.xtext    Grammar Problem
>   No available bundle exports package 'org.apache.log4j'  MANIFEST.MF /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui/META-INF    line 15 Plug-in Problem

Comment: which options did you select in the "new xtext project wizard"? do you have any errors on the manifest? can you show a screenshot of your project structure in the package explorer?

Comment: hi Christian, I've put the answers as an update on the question. The unresolved references I do not know how to resolve. As I understand these are not .jars I need to add? I can't find relevant .jars

Comment: can you recreate the projects. it looks like the pde install did not work or did not pick up the data

Comment: and: you you have build automatically enabled?

Comment: additionallly you might have to reload/check the target platform in the window preferences menu.

Comment: FIXED IT! It was the target platform.

Comment: I did preferences -> plug-in development -> target platform -> add -> default [...]

Comment: Many thanks Christian, I spent a long long time trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you target platform is not broken or missing: Window -> Preferences -> Search for "Target Platform"